# pandas using list comprehension to create new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have list of date range and dataframe as below:
[('2019-01-01', '2019-01-04'),
 ('2019-12-25', '2019-12-28'),
 ('2019-18-29', '2019-12-21'),]

```
+------------+---+------+
|    date    | id|      |
+------------+---+------+
| 2018-01-04 | 1 |      |
| 2018-01-02 | 1 |      |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-28 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-27 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-26 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-25 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-21 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-20 | 1 |      |
| 2017-12-18 | 1 |      |
+------------+---+------+
```

expected output:

```
+------------+---+------+-------+
|    date    |id | group|       |
+------------+---+------+-------+
| 2018-01-04 | 1 |    1 |       |
| 2018-01-02 | 1 |    1 |       |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 |    1 |       |
| 2017-12-28 | 1 |    2 |       |
| 2017-12-27 | 1 |    2 |       |
| 2017-12-26 | 1 |    2 |       |
| 2017-12-25 | 1 |    2 |       |
| 2017-12-21 | 1 |    3 |       |
| 2017-12-20 | 1 |    3 |       |
| 2017-12-18 | 1 |    3 |       |
+------------+---+------+-------+
```

I tried use list comprehension to assign 1 if date <= "2019-01-04" & date >= "2019-01-01" and so on, but it doesn't work.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you manually assign these ranges? Or is there a logic behind that?

Comment: i assign it manually, logic here i want is just group by date column with condition given date range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def f(x):
    if (x <= pd.Timestamp('2018-01-04')) & (x >= pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')):
        return(1)
    elif (x <= pd.Timestamp('2017-12-28')) & (x >= pd.Timestamp('2017-12-25')):
        return(2)
    elif (x <= pd.Timestamp('2017-12-20')) & (x >= pd.Timestamp('2017-12-18')):
        return(3)

df['group'] = df['date'].apply(f)
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
date_ranges = [pd.date_range(start='2018-01-04', end='2018-01-01'), 
pd.date_range(start='2017/12/25', end='2017/12/28'),
pd.date_range(start='2017/12/18', end='2017/12/20'),
]

df['group'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: [i for i, date_rng in enumerate(date_ranges) if x in date_rng][0])
```

Comment: to be more flexible, how can i input date range as parameter of function: date_range = [('2019-01-01', '2019-01-04'), ('2019-12-25', '2019-12-28'), ('2019-18-29', '2019-12-21')], then for ex: can replace pd.Timestamp('2018-01-04')) by date_range[0][1]

Comment: @Kleine See the above edit. Not exactly as you requested, but having `date range` as a parameter to be inputted would make things more complicated.

Comment: @Kleine Great! Happy to help.